# Setting Tar compression level in Win10

Tags: powershell, windows-10, compression, tar

I created a powershell command in order to compress mdb files from a certain folder. The structure looks like this:

```
C:\Projects\MySoftware\templates\A\a.mdb
C:\Projects\MySoftware\templates\B\b.mdb
C:\Projects\MySoftware\templates\C\c.mdb
```

Basically I want that my archive must contains the directories with "templates" as root node. So:

```
templates\A\a.mdb
templates\B\b.mdb
templates\C\c.mdb
```

And in PowerShell

```
powershell -Command "$pa = 'C:\Projects'; Set-Location C:\Projects\MySoftware\; gci -Path templates -Recurse -Include *.mdb  | sort LastWriteTime  | ForEach-Object {  cd 'C:\Projects\MySoftware\'; $fn = $_.Fullname; tar rf BASetupUpdate.tgz $($fn.Replace('C:\Projects\MySoftware\','')) }"
```

The tar creates correctly the archive but without compression. I'm struggling with command line and help in order to set the compression level.

Comment: 'tar` by design do not compress. External modules/programs like `gzip` compress the archive

Comment: @RomeoNinov Actually, no. All modern implementations of the `tar` command now have options to compress directly.

Comment: @MarkAdler, please check `tar` on Solaris, AIX, HP-UX.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Ok. Checked Solaris: `$ uname -a
SunOS gcc-solaris11 5.11 11.3 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise
$ tar --help
...
  -z, -j, -J, --lzma  Compress archive with gzip/bzip2/xz/lzma
...`

Comment: @RomeoNinov and AIX: `$ uname -a
AIX power8-aix 2 7 00F9C1964C00
$ gtar --help
...
  -z, --gzip, --gunzip, --ungzip   filter the archive through gzip
...`

Comment: I'm not finding an HP-UX system.

Comment: @MarkAdler, the tars you check are GNU versions, native one do not have it.

Comment: Yet there they are, and those are modern implementations of tar. It's the only tar on that Solaris system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `z` option to compress, which cannot be used with `r`, only `c`. You would need to make a list of all the things you want to put in the tar file, and use a single invocation of the `tar` command with all of those names. You cannot incrementally add files to a compressed tar.gz (or .tgz if you prefer) archive. So something like:

```
tar -czf archive.tgz file1 file2 ... filen
```

As for the compression level, you can add `--option gzip:compression-level=9`. However to start, you should leave it at the default level and see if that meets your needs. Higher compression levels can take much more time for a small reduction in size.